# Check if value from one list is present in another list using stream

Tags: java, list, collections, java-stream

I have `List<RegionCountry> regionCountries` of:

```
class RegionCountry {
    Region region;
    List<Country> countries;
   }
```

And Region and Country looks like:

```
class Region {
    Long regionId;
    String regionName;
}

class Country {
    Long countryId;
    String countryName;
}
```

Each Region have multiple countries within them. I am getting `List<Long> countryIds` and `List<Long> regionIds` from the UI which I want to compare against this `regionCountries`. So I did something like:

```
List<RegionCountry> filteredList = regionCountries
                            .stream()
                            .filter(regionCountry -> regionIds.contains(regionCountry.getRegion().getRegionId()))
                            .filter(regionCountry -> regionCountry.getCountries()
                                                    .stream()
                                                    .allMatch(country -> countryIds.contains(country.getCountryId())))
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

But it is not returning anything. I am trying to figure out how to compare `List<Long> countryIds` with `List<Country> countries` of `RegionCountry`. Is there any better approach to do it in `Java 8` or `8+` using `stream API`? Or can it be simplified by using any other approach?

Comment: I don't clearly understand what is the difference between the classes `RegionCountry ` and `Region`  in terms of their responsibilities? Can the `Region` class alone substitute them both?

Comment: According to your problem could you provide an example of input?

Comment: @alexander-ivanchenko No, `RegionCountry` Indicates Region(Ex. Asia, Europe etc) and List of countries within that Region(Ex. UK, Germany within Europe). While `Region` only indicates one Single region, we cannot replace other classes by  `Region`. Input could be any `List<Long>`  which indicates region or country Ids

Comment: Got it. How about an example of `countryIds`, `regionIds ` and `regionCountries` to reproduce the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The presented code seems to be fine and working, so the actual datasets need to be checked if they meet the provided condition:
`regionIds` contain `rc.regionId` AND `countryIds` contain IDs of all countries.

[Online demo (using `record` instead of classes to avoid boilerplate code)](https://www.jdoodle.com/iembed/v0/nEJ):

```
non-filtered
RegionCountry[region=Region[regionId=1, regionName=Europe], countries=[Country[countryId=1, countryName=Albania], Country[countryId=2, countryName=Andorra], Country[countryId=6, countryName=Germany]]]
RegionCountry[region=Region[regionId=3, regionName=America], countries=[Country[countryId=15, countryName=Canada], Country[countryId=16, countryName=US]]]
region ids: [3, 1]
country ids: [1, 2, 3, 15, 6]
filtered
RegionCountry[region=Region[regionId=1, regionName=Europe], countries=[Country[countryId=1, countryName=Albania], Country[countryId=2, countryName=Andorra], Country[countryId=6, countryName=Germany]]]
```

A minor optimization would be to use `Set` instead of `List` for `regionIds`, `countryIds` to make faster checks with `Set::contains`.